# Blocks / tiles aren't responding to clicks

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints, puzzle

I've recently finished a tutorial, [UE4 Slide Puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-R3tLHfSH8) by Nicholas Thompson. Halfway through the second tutorial, I found out that the blocks / tiles wouldn't respond to my clicks. For example, when I clicked on a tile, it wouldn't print out a Hello message.

I have watched the tutorial so many times already, I've searched it up, looked at my code thoroughly, and I can't find any problems. Here are my blueprints:

1. [Event Graph](https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/k52j3fm9/)
2. [Get Move To (Function)](https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/qv6ohlub/)

After some debugging, I found out that the problem occured at the start of the function, Mesh Clicked in the Event Graph.

Please help, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us what debugging results led you to discover 'the problem occurred at the start od the function..." — did you find a specific error message or other symptom we could use as a hint?

Comment: No, no errors. I just debugged by placing Print Strings.

Comment: Have you set the option to input mode Game and UI?  If Unreal is not "listening" for the UI (which is how I've assumed you've done this) to be clicked on, no events will be called.

Comment: @Stephen hi, what do you mean by 'set the option'? What option, and where? Thank you!

Comment: You can set the input mode.  Game only, game and UI or UI only.  If your game is expecting UI only then it won't respond to any clicks inside the game area.  Pull off a pin from the Begin Play and set the mode accordingly.

Comment: @Stephen so I tried it, and in the link, the video is the result, and the image is the picture of what I used. Here: https://ufile.io/f/wt4hj

Comment: @Stephen could you show an image of what you mean if possible, please? Thank you!

Comment: On your image, you haven't got anything linked to the Custom Event of Mesh Clicked into Set Clicked Mesh.  These should definitely be joined.

Comment: @Stephen, thank you, I forgot to join them after I debugged it, I joined them just now, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Kupachu I'm sorry, I don't know what to say.  I've done this tutorial now to see if it happens to me and it does not.  The clicks work fine.  The only thing I can suggest is that you've accidentally changed something in the Static Mesh settings so it is not responding to the clicks.  In the Add Static Mesh Component box, make sure that under Collision, Generate Overlap events is ticked and Collision Presets is set to "Block All Dynamic"

Comment: @Stephen thank you a lot for your help and your time. I will try that, but I've also found something that might help: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1671773-onclicked-event-not-firing

Comment: @Stephen, so I created a new third person project and copied-pasted all my previous code and created new variables, it didn't work. Then, I hooked up Mesh Clicked with Print String, and it worked when I clicked on it! So that meant I fixed the Bind Events, but now it must have somsething to do with sliding?

Comment: I've also checked the timeline and it's all right.